# How do i use the foreach loop to output the value array of 'winner' in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, foreach

```
$famousMeals = [
    1 => ['name' => 'Currywurst mit Pommes',
        'winner' => [2001, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2020]],
    2 => ['name' => 'Hähnchencrossies mit Paprikareis',
        'winner' => [2002, 2004, 2008]],
    3 => ['name' => 'Spaghetti Bolognese',
        'winner' => [2011, 2012, 2017]],
    4 => ['name' => 'Jägerschnitzel mit Pommes',
        'winner' => 2019]
];
```

Question like above. I've tried everything:(

Answer (score 0):

Use [array_column](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and loop it

```
$famousMeals = [
    1 => ['name' => 'Currywurst mit Pommes',
        'winner' => [2001, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2020]],
    2 => ['name' => 'Hähnchencrossies mit Paprikareis',
        'winner' => [2002, 2004, 2008]],
    3 => ['name' => 'Spaghetti Bolognese',
        'winner' => [2011, 2012, 2017]],
    4 => ['name' => 'Jägerschnitzel mit Pommes',
        'winner' => 2019]
];

$winners = array_column($famousMeals,'winner');

foreach($winners as $winner) {
  print_r($winner);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use foreach an access any position of the parent array like this

```
<?php

$famousMeals = [
    1 => ['name' => 'Currywurst mit Pommes',
        'winner' => [2001, 2003, 2007, 2010, 2020]],
    2 => ['name' => 'Hähnchencrossies mit Paprikareis',
        'winner' => [2002, 2004, 2008]],
    3 => ['name' => 'Spaghetti Bolognese',
        'winner' => [2011, 2012, 2017]],
    4 => ['name' => 'Jägerschnitzel mit Pommes',
        'winner' => 2019]
];

foreach($famousMeals as $meal) {
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Meal: " . $meal['name'] . "\n";
    echo "Winners: " . json_encode($meal['winner']);
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Note that the position $meal['winner'] is an array, so you have to use json_encode to display the data.